# socat how to receive large amount of messages store these messages and acknowledge each message

Tags: socat

i need to to be able to receive a large amount of messages which may arrive at the same time, store and append these messages and reply to each message with 'ok'. I have tried socat TCP-LISTEN:5678,reuseaddr,fork open:/home/derek/raw2.txt,system:'echo +OK' and various combinations to do this but cannot get it all to work. I am able to either receive a message and send back 'ok' or receive a message and store it. I am unable to get my brain cell to do both together. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is quite old now, this would have worked:

```
socat tcp-listen:5678,reuseaddr,fork 'system:echo +OK!!open:recv.data,create,append'
```

Source: [Dual inter addresses](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-addresschain.html)